# LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol, searched for in a non-existing *.obj file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, lnk2019

Good morning,
I have just inherited an application from a collegue who has left, and I'm already in trouble: the last thing we have done is porting the solution from Visual Studio 2010 to 2013.
Now while building one of the projects in the solution, I get following error message:
`1>usharedmemory.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl C_NamedSemaphore::C_NamedSemaphore(char const *,unsigned int)" (??0C_NamedSemaphore@@QEAA@PEBDI@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl C_RecursiveNamedSemaphore::C_RecursiveNamedSemaphore(char const *,unsigned int)" (??0C_RecursiveNamedSemaphore@@QEAA@PEBDI@Z)`
This error seems to be caused within the file "Y:\Ucam5\ucm\x\rip_mlfdpf\usharedmemory.obj" (within the project's directory), but after having a quick look, it seems that this *.obj file does not even exist.
Hence the next question: what can I do in order to be sure that the *.obj file gets created? I have already verified that the "usharedmemory.cpp" file is present in the directory of the main project (the corresponding *.h files is located in the "External Dependencies" chapter, which makes me believe that the *.obj file will be created during the build of the main project.
You see my problem: my project refers to a file which the project needs to create, but as the project does not create the file, he obviously can't refer to it, you see the circle I'm running in :-)

(for your information, I have no idea on how to generate an "*.obj" file)

Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe the project dependencies are ordered wrong. The project which is looking for the `.obj` file is being built **before** the project which will generate the `.obj` file. Hence, the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning,
I have finally solved my issue. As a good citizen, I will describe how I have done it :-), but as a less good programmer, I need to admit that I don't understand how my actions solve the problem ;-(
I have done a file comparison of both *.vcxproj Visual Project files (the old one from VC2010 and the new VC2013 one). In that way I have seen that the "umultiproc.cpp" entry was missing in the VC2013 one:
`<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">`
`...`
`<ItemGroup>`
`...`
`<ClCompile Include="..\..\mp\umultiproc.cpp" /> <!-- missing -->`

Summary: In the error message, there was an unresolved symbol (C_Semaphore constructor), which was defined in *.cpp/*.h source/header file. In order to solve the error, I have added a reference to the *.cpp source file into the VC2013 project file.

Answer (score 2):

Object files (`*.obj`) are created directly from source files (`*.cpp`) by the compiler at compilation time, for each source file in your project.

The error you are receiving is **not** caused by *usharedmemory.obj* not existing; it should be created in the *Debug* or *Release* folders.

The error you are getting is because *usharedmemory.cpp* uses the `C_NamedSemaphore(char const *,unsigned int)`-constructor of `C_NamedSemaphore` and the definition of the constructor can not be found in any of the source files. This constructor is used in the `C_RecursiveNamedSemaphore(char const *,unsigned int)`-constructor defined in *usharedmemory.cpp*. This is what the error message reads.

To solve this, you need to find out where the constructor of `C_NamedSemaphore` is defined (which source file) and ensure that this source file is included in your project. Or, if it is in a library file (static or dynamic), verify that this library file is included as an *Additional Dependency* (under `project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`; ensure you set this for **all** builds, not just the currently active one).